# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'activity' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Here is my exception:

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
四月 18, 2017 6:11:37 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
严重: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'activity' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.customer_002dform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(customer_002dform_jsp.java:427)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.customer_002dform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(customer_002dform_jsp.java:381)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.customer_002dform_jsp._jspService(customer_002dform_jsp.java:248)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And the following is my relevant code including using simpleformcontroller

```html
<div>
  <p>Create new moment</p>     
  <form:form action="add-moment.htm" commandName="activity" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <form:input path="content"/><br/>
  Select photo: <input type="file" name="photo"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="publish">
  </form:form>
</div>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add-moment.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String publishMoment(ModelMap model) { 

        Activity activity = new Activity();
        model.addAttribute("activity", activity); 
        return "customer-form"; 
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/add-moment.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addMomentAjax(@ModelAttribute("activity") Activity activity , HttpServletRequest request){

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Customer user = (Customer) session.getAttribute("customer");
        PersonDAO personDao = new PersonDAO();

        try{
            File directory;

            String check = File.separator;
            String path = null;
            if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("\\")) {
                path = servletContext.getRealPath("").replace("build\\", ""); // gives real path as Lab9/build/web/
                                                                              // so we need to replace build in the path
                                                                                    }

            if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
                path = servletContext.getRealPath("").replace("build/", "");
                path += "/"; // Adding trailing slash for Mac systems.
            }
            directory = new File(path + "\\" + activity.getActivityID());
            boolean temp = directory.exists();
            if (!temp) {
                temp = directory.mkdir();
            }
            if (temp) {
                // We need to transfer to a file
                CommonsMultipartFile photoInMemory = activity.getPhoto();

                String fileName = photoInMemory.getOriginalFilename();
                // could generate file names as well

                File localFile = new File(directory.getPath(), fileName);

                // move the file from memory to the file

                photoInMemory.transferTo(localFile);
                activity.setPhotoName(localFile.getPath());
                System.out.println("File is stored at " + localFile.getPath());
                personDao.insertActivity(activity, user.getPersonID());

            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ModelAndView("customer-form");
    }
}
```

It seems that I forget some configurations so that the page can not extract the "activity" pojo. I found many similar problems on Stack Overflow but it didn't work when I tried these solutions.

Comment: Can you briefly describe which solutions you tried and failed? In the given code snippets everything seems to be correct. You can go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42198051/7456075)  really carefully. It is very detailed and covered all possible scenarios.

Comment: Also make sure that your Activity class has getter-setter methods for the `content` property.

Comment: It is solved already ^-^. I added the plain pojo in a wrong place. So the page which contains <form: form> cannot find the pojo named "activity".

Comment: Thanks all the same !!!

Comment: Why don't you add your solution as an answer? It may help anyone in future.