# Thymeleaf errors when doing mvc tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, thymeleaf, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to test my controller that takes the form for updating supplier

```
//get supplier form for update
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getSupplierUpdateForm(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        if(supplierRepository.findById(id).isPresent()){
            model.addAttribute("supplier",supplierRepository.findById(id).get());
        }
        return "supplier";
    }
```

so far I was able to write this test

```
@Test
public void testGetSupplierUpdateForm()throws Exception{

    Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
    supplier.setId((long)1);
    supplier.setSupplierName("ABC Company");
    supplier.setAddress("Bayombong, Nueva Vizcaya");
    supplier.setContactNumber("N/A");



    if(this.supplierRepository.findById((long)1).isPresent()){
        given(this.supplierRepository.findById((long)1).get()).willReturn(supplier);
    }
    mvc.perform(get("/supplier/1"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(view().name("supplier"))
    .andExpect(model().attributeExists("supplier"))
    .andExpect(model().attribute("supplier", equalTo(supplier)));                           
}
```

but when I run it I get this error

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during
>   execution of processor
>   'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'
>   (template: "supplier" - line 16, col 25)

Line 16 from my view looks like this

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
```

I also get errors from these kinds of lines

```
<title th:text="${#strings.isEmpty(supplier.id) ? 'New Supplier' : 'Update Supplier '+supplier.id }"></title>
```

I think it has something to do with the supplier entity.
Am I doing this test right? What can I do to fix these problems?

After Investigating a bit I found that

```
if(this.supplierRepository.findById((long)1).isPresent()){
        given(this.supplierRepository.findById((long)1).get()).willReturn(supplier);
    }
```

is not returning doing anything since

```
this.supplierRepository.findById((long)1).isPresent()
```

is false.

How can I make use of findById in a given()?

Comment: Maybe this a dupl. of [What causes “java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198050/what-causes-java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-ta)?

Comment: I think it has something to do with Spring data 2.0.0 findById. if(this.supplierRepository.findById(1L).isPresent()){
   given(this.supplierRepository.findById(1L).get()).willReturn(supplier);
     } is not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it by changing

```
if(this.supplierRepository.findById((long)1).isPresent()){
        given(this.supplierRepository.findById((long)1).get()).willReturn(supplier);
    }
```

to

```
given(this.supplierRepository.findById(1L)).willReturn(Optional.of(supplier));
```

The problem was the first stub was returning null