# How to fix "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'skill' available as request attribute" error

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Getting the error seen in the title as well as "Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "profile" - line 35, col 48)" which is line 4 below in html. How can this be fixed? I looked through a lot of similar questions and most were using a method with @RequestMapping instead of the @PostMapping.

```
@Controller
public class SkillController {

    @Autowired
    private SkillRepository skillRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @GetMapping("/profile/{path}/skill")
    public String view(@PathVariable String path, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("skill", new Skill());
        return "redirect:/profile/" + path;
    }

    @PostMapping("/profile/{path}/skill")
    public String addSkill(@PathVariable String path, @ModelAttribute("skill") Skill skill, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:/profile/" + path;
        }
        try {
            Account a = accountRepository.findByPath(path);
            a.getSkills().add(skill);
            accountRepository.save(a);
            return "redirect:/profile/" + path;
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("name", "name", " Please try again!");
            return "redirect:/profile/" + path;
        }
    }

}
```

```
<form th:action="@{/profile/{path}/skill(path=${path})}" th:object="${skill}" method="POST">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/></td>
                        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Character error.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>   
                        <td><button type="submit">Add skill</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Skill extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 4, max = 16)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198050/what-causes-java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-ta)

Answer (score 0):

For passing attributes on redirects, [RedirectAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) should be used instead of [Model](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html):

```
@GetMapping("/profile/{path}/skill")
public String view(@PathVariable String path, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("skill", new Skill());
    return "redirect:/profile/" + path;
}
```