# Why am I getting this exception in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:271)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.todo_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(todo_jsp.java:242)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.todo_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(todo_jsp.java:193)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.todo_jsp._jspService(todo_jsp.java:144)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

---

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<html> 
<head>
<title>First Web Application</title>
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 

<div class="container">
<%-- Add To Do Page for ${name}  --%>
    <form:form method="post" commandName="todo">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <form:label path="desc">Description</form:label> 
                <form:input path="desc" type="text"
                    class="form-control" required="required"/>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
      <%-- Description: <input name="desc" type="text"/> <input type="submit"/> --%>
    </form:form>
</div>
    <script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
package com.myspringboot.springboot.springbootfirstwebapplication.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class ToDo {
    
    private int id;
    private String user;
    private String desc;
    private Date targetDate;
    private boolean isDone;

    public ToDo() {
        super();
    }
    
    public ToDo(int id, String user, String desc, Date targetDate,
            boolean isDone) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
        this.isDone = isDone;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Date getTargetDate() {
        return targetDate;
    }

    public void setTargetDate(Date targetDate) {
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return isDone;
    }

    public void setDone(boolean isDone) {
        this.isDone = isDone;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        ToDo other = (ToDo) obj;
        if (id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Todo [id=%s, user=%s, desc=%s, targetDate=%s, isDone=%s]", id,
                user, desc, targetDate, isDone);
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.myspringboot.springboot.springbootfirstwebapplication.controller;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.myspringboot.springboot.springbootfirstwebapplication.model.ToDo;
import com.myspringboot.springboot.springbootfirstwebapplication.service.ToDoService;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("name")
public class ToDoController {
    
    @Autowired
    ToDoService service;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/list-todos", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String showToDoList(ModelMap model) {
        String name = (String)model.get("name");
        //System.out.println("this is the comment " + name);
        model.put("todos", service.retrieveToDos(name));
        return "list-todos";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/add-todo", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String showAddToDoPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("todo", new ToDo( 0, (String)model.get("name"), "", 
                new Date(), false) );
        return "todo";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/delete-todo", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String deleteToDo(@RequestParam int id) {
        service.deleteToDo(id);
        return "redirect:/list-todos";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/add-todo", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    //public String addToDo(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String desc) {
    public String addToDo(ModelMap model, ToDo todo) {
        //service.addToDo((String) model.get("name"), desc, new Date(), false);
        service.addToDo((String) model.get("name"), todo.getDesc(), new Date(), false);
        // To get the list-todos page to show the list of todos we could use 
        // the following statement - this duplicates the implementation
        //model.put("todos", service.retrieveToDos(name);
        return "redirect:/list-todos";
    }       
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're showing us everything?  I could very well be missing something, but given that the error message is complaining about something named `command`, I would expect to find that word used somewhere in your code, but I don't see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198050/what-causes-java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-ta)

Comment: What more can I add to the information provided? Please let me know.