# Thymleaf ->Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to fetch add-journeyFooOrder view and unable to do(getting view saying - **Whitelabel Error Page**) so please help me by letting me know what I am doing wrong here and why. Thanks in advance

So when first I hit **localhost:8080** then I am able to get **index.html** from there I click on the link to add order then I should get redirected to **add-journeyFoodOrder.html** view where I am getting the error(please view controller code that will give more clarity). Error logs are as:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during
> execution of processor
> 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'
> (template: "add-journeyFoodOrder" - line 19, col 29)  at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1393)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]  at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]  at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na] Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
> target object for bean name 'journeyFoodOrder' available as request
> attribute     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]  at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]

**view add-journeyFoodOrder.html**

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/addJourneyFoodOrder}" th:object="${journeyFoodOrder}" method="post">
                <label for="nameOfCenter">Name of Center</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{nameOfCenter}" placeholder="Name of Center">
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nameOfCenter')}" th:errors="*{nameOfCenter}"></span>
                
                <label for="nameOfGuide">Name of Guide</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{nameOfGuide}" placeholder="Name of Guide">
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nameOfGuide')}" th:errors="*{nameOfGuide}"></span>
                
                <label for="headCount">Head count</label>
                <input type="number" th:field="*{headCount}" placeholder="Head count">
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('headCount')}" th:errors="*{headCount}"></span>
                
                <label for="dateOfJourney">Mobile No Of Guide</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{contactNoOfGuide}" placeholder="Mobile No Of Guide">
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('contactNoOfGuide')}" th:errors="*{contactNoOfGuide}"></span>
                
                <label for="dateOfDeparture">Date of departure</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{dateOfDeparture}" placeholder="Date Of departure">
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dateOfDeparture')}" th:errors="*{dateOfDeparture}"></span>
                
                <label for="mealRetrievalTime">Meal retrieval time</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{mealRetrievalTime}" placeholder="Mobile No Of Guide">
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('mealRetrievalTime')}" th:errors="*{mealRetrievalTime}"></span>
                
                <input type="submit" value="Add Order">   
            </form>
        </div>
```

**JourneyFoodOrderController class**

```
@Controller
public class JourneyFoodOrderController {
    
    private final JourneyFoodOrderRepository journeyFoodOrderRepository;

    @Autowired
    public JourneyFoodOrderController(JourneyFoodOrderRepository journeyFoodOrderRepository) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.journeyFoodOrderRepository = journeyFoodOrderRepository;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String showSignUpForm(JourneyFoodOrderRepository journeyFoodOrderRepository) {
        return "add-journeyFoodOrder";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/addJourneyFoodOrder")
    public String addJourneyFoodOrder(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="journeyFoodOrder") JourneyFoodOrder journeyFoodOrder, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-journeyFoodOrder";
        }
        model.addAttribute("journeyFoodOrder", journeyFoodOrder);
        journeyFoodOrderRepository.save(journeyFoodOrder);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String showJourneyFoodOrderList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("journeyFoodOrders", journeyFoodOrderRepository.findAll());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**POJO is**

```
@Entity
public class JourneyFoodOrder{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JourneyFoodOrder [id=" + id + ", nameOfCenter=" + nameOfCenter + ", nameOfGuide=" + nameOfGuide
                + ", headCount=" + headCount + ", contactNoOfGuide=" + contactNoOfGuide + ", dateOfDeparture="
                + dateOfDeparture + ", mealRetrievalTime=" + mealRetrievalTime + "]";
    }

    @NotBlank(message = "Name Of Center is mandatory")
    private String nameOfCenter;

    @NotBlank(message = "Name Of Guide is mandatory")
    private String nameOfGuide;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Head Count is mandatory")
    private int headCount;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Mobile No Of Guide is mandatory")
    private String contactNoOfGuide;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Date of Journey is mandatory")
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Journey meal retrival date and time is mandatory")
    private Date mealRetrievalTime;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNameOfCenter() {
        return nameOfCenter;
    }

    public void setNameOfCenter(String nameOfCenter) {
        this.nameOfCenter = nameOfCenter;
    }

    public int getHeadCount() {
        return headCount;
    }

    public void setHeadCount(int headCount) {
        this.headCount = headCount;
    }

    public String getNameOfGuide() {
        return nameOfGuide;
    }

    public void setNameOfGuide(String nameOfGuide) {
        this.nameOfGuide = nameOfGuide;
    }

    public String getContactNoOfGuide() {
        return contactNoOfGuide;
    }

    public void setContactNoOfGuide(String contactNoOfGuide) {
        this.contactNoOfGuide = contactNoOfGuide;
    }

    public Date getDateOfDeparture() {
        return dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public void setDateOfDeparture(Date dateOfDeparture) {
        this.dateOfDeparture = dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public Date getMealRetrievalTime() {
        return mealRetrievalTime;
    }

    public void setMealRetrievalTime(Date mealRetrievalTime) {
        this.mealRetrievalTime = mealRetrievalTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you researched the root cause error mentioned in the stack trace you provided? "_Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'journeyFoodOrder' available as request attribute_". There are several questions and answers on SO relating to this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198050/what-causes-java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-ta)

Comment: I got it what you are saying but  I was referring to this https://baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf where they have not added it in signup method(and that code (https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/…) is working fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the object which you reference in `th:object`:

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/addJourneyFoodOrder}" th:object="${journeyFoodOrder}" method="post">
```

I see that you mention it but there is no adding of this model attribute inside the GET mapping.
Add this from your GET mapping and it should work just fine.

**LE:**

You can also use this variant:

```
@GetMapping("/signup") public String showSignUpForm(JourneyFoodOrder journeyFoodOrder) { return "add-journeyFoodOrder"; }
```

Comment: But still I am not getting why I have to add model attribute in GET method(/signup one) when I have already added it in addJourneyFoodOrder method. By the way I was referring to this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf  where they have not added it in signup method(and that code (https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-crud) is working fine).

Comment: I edited my answer with another variant of the solution.
You pointed out some solutions which are not how you implemented those.
In the #showSignUpForm you injected a repository instance, not the object that you want to bind automatically to the model and form.

Comment: @Shivam did you test with what I suggested? Injecting the JourneyFoodOrder instance in the showSignUpForm() method?