# Can't create post request in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I tried to create `POST` request to send my `form` to the `Spring` server, but I'm only getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'form' available as request attribute
```

My controller content:

```java
// Form post handler
@PostMapping("/")
public String home(@ModelAttribute Form form, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Form form_new = g.fromJson(JavaWebApplication.runtimeJsonContent, Form.class);
    model.addAttribute("form", form);
    model.addAttribute("ip", form.IP);
    model.addAttribute("gateway", form.Gateway);
    model.addAttribute("port", form.Port);
    model.addAttribute("IncomingConnections", form.IncomingConnections);
    return "index";
}
```

Here is my Form model:

```java
public class Form {
    public String IP;
    public String Gateway;
    public int Port;
    public boolean IncomingConnections;
    public int QoSEnable = 0;

    public Form(){}
    public Form(String IP, String gateway, int port, boolean incomingConnections) {
        this.IP = IP;
        this.Gateway = gateway;
        this.Port = port;
        this.IncomingConnections = incomingConnections;
        this.QoSEnable = 0; // Assert that 0 is default
        ExportToJson(this);
    }
    public Form(String IP, String gateway, int port, boolean incomingConnections, int qosEnable) {
        this.IP = IP;
        this.Gateway = gateway;
        this.Port = port;
        this.IncomingConnections = incomingConnections;
        this.QoSEnable = qosEnable;
        ExportToJson(this);
    }
}
```

And my `index.html` webpage bound on `/` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{./styles/main.css}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${form}">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="https://kable-swiatlowodowe.net.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/mikrotik.png" width="20%" style="margin-bottom: 5%;">
        <br>
        <div id="input-el">
        <div class="input-element"><input type="text" placeholder="IP" name="IP" th:value="${ip}" th:field="*{IP}" id="input-element-ip"></div>
        <div class="input-element"><input type="text" placeholder="Gateway" th:value="${gateway}" th:field="*{Gateway}" name="Gateway" id="input-element-gateway"></div>
        <div class="input-element"><input type="number" placeholder="Port" th:value="${port}" th:field="*{Port}" name="Port" id="input-element-port"></div>

    </div>
        <div id="checkbox-el">
        Incoming connections:<br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" th:checked="${IncomingConnections}" th:field="*{IncomingConnections}" name="conections" id="conections-el">Allow</label>
    </div>

        QoS Mode<br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="qos-mode-el" id="input-radio-game-first" checked>Game First</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="qos-mode-el" id="input-radio-multimedia-first">Multimedia First</label>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample Postman request:
[image: request]

Response for this request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <div id="container">
            <img src="https://kable-swiatlowodowe.net.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/mikrotik.png" width="20%" style="margin-bottom: 5%;">
            <br>
            <div id="input-el">
                <div class="input-element">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="IP" name="IP" value="" id="input-element-ip"></div>
                    <div class="input-element">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Gateway" value=""name="Gateway" id="input-element-gateway"></div>
                        <div class="input-element">
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Port" value="0" name="Port" id="input-element-port"></div>

                        </div>
                        <div id="checkbox-el">
                            Incoming connections:<br>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="conections" id="conections-el">Allow</label>
                        </div>

                        QoS Mode<br>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="qos-mode-el" id="input-radio-game-first" checked>Game First</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="qos-mode-el" id="input-radio-multimedia-first">Multimedia First</label>
                        <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Each value content is clear**
[image: form]

Any idea how to make this binding work correctly?

Comment: have you tested it with Postman?

Comment: nope, but you got the point, i will try.

Comment: I checked and I guess i don't know how to parse data in post in java

Comment: Start here and work your way through all the information it contains: [What causes “java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198050/what-causes-java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-ta). If you are still stuck, after that, you can update your question with your findings from that exercise.

Comment: Ok that explains errors in my index.html file but what about null values in sended Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not passing the form object to your thymeleaf template

Do this -

```
@GETMapping("/")
public String getHome(Model model){
model.addAttribute("form", new Form());
return "index";
}
```

This will return a Form object to your thymleaf and then it can process the data in your code --

```
<form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${form}">
      // This will now receive form object
</form>
```

Comment: But @Ayush, will it still work as intended? I mean user on main page has a form with values from json, then when he change any value and then send this form back this data can be processed and he will get this same site with changed values?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be 
`@POSTMapping("/")` instead of `@GETMapping("/")` ? cause we are using POST method

Comment: yes it must have @POSTMapping("/") also for processing the form data... The flow is like this -> @GETMapping("/")  this will give a Form object in index page where you can store value using th:field="*{IP}"  now when you click on  submit ithe Form object will be processed by the @POSTMapping("/") controller.... Thats why i wrote get mapping as post mapping you already wrote ....so just include both and will work fine......

Comment: Flow of program--

1. you enter url in browser and searched for index page.
2. Now GET MAPPING will give you INDEX+ Form  object(your model Class)
3. On submit  Request will be processed by @POST MAPPING

Comment: Did it worked for you ?  Then please accept my answer 