# How to solve thymeleaf template parsing error

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to present a html to screen but I'm getting template parser error from thymeleaf.
Here is my code and error:

index.html:

```
<body>
    <h2>My ToDo List</h2>
    <form action="/send-form-data" method="post" th:object="${myForm}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{title}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Decription:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{description}"/></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class TodolistController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/display-form", "/index.html" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayForm() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
    mv.addObject("myForm", new MyModel());

    return mv;
}
```

}

MyModel:

```
public class MyModel {

private String title;
private String description;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

Error:

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 15, col 28)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'formData' available as request attribute
```

I tried something but not helped. When I delete the inputs from HTML it works finely so problem is about matching thymeleaf fields with MyModel variables but I couldn't solve.

Comment: You have a getter called `getDescription1()` (with a `1` in the method name) - but it looks like the form is expecting it to be called `getDescription()` instead.

Comment: If that does not fix the issue, can you tell us which line is line 15 of your `index.html` template - as shown in the error message `template: "index" - line 15, col 28`.

Comment: I fixed the that part of code and updated the question with another error but problem is still same. Line 15 is:
`<td><input type="text" th:field="*{title}"/></td>`

Comment: Do you close <form> and <body> tags?

Comment: yes, table, form, body and html all closed.

Comment: You can work through all of the answers here: [What causes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42198050/12567365)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your program, and I consider that you entered a wrong url in your browser. Because there is nothing wrong in your code.

According to your controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = { "/display-form", "/index.html" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

**Please make sure your browser's url is:**

`<host>:<port>/<context-path>/index.html` or `<host>:<port>/<context-path>/display-form`

**instead of** `<host>:<port>/<context-path>/`.

The problem is, `<host>:<port>/<context-path>/` is the default welcome page and Spring directly renders your `index.html` without passing through your Controller. This is why you got a IllegalStateException with BindingResult issue.

[image]

---

But if you entered a correct url path, then you will see expected page:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just from the error message I would assume the target object you want to fill is missing or the way you currently provide it does not work.
You can adjust your controller method to look like

```
@Controller
public class TodolistController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/display-form", "/index.html" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("myForm", new MyModel());
    return "index";
}
```

Assuming your index.html is located in resources/templates