# How to convert a string to date in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have the following input:

```
<input name="dateOfOrder" class="form-control" id="dateOfOrder" type="date" th:field="*{{dateOfOrder}}" />
```

And oh this is the fragment of the DTO into which they are inserted :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate dateOfOrder;
```

Unfortunately I get an exception:

> Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
> [java.time.LocalDate] from value '2022-06-14'; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed from value
> [2022-06-14].

I`m not proficient in Thymeleaf and would like some hints on what is wrong here

Comment: Comment from the answer (should be added to the question, really): "_neither bindingresult nor plain target object for bean name '#dates' available as request attribute_" - in case it helps, see [What causes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42198050/12567365)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Thymeleaf formatting.

```
<input name="dateOfOrder" class="form-control" id="dateOfOrder" type="date" th:field="${#dates.format(dateOfOrder, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}" />
```

Comment: Does this work? I only ask because the Thymeleaf `#dates` utility methods are for `java.util.Date` objects (which should be avoided at all costs these days). The question uses a Java `time.LocalDate`, typically handled by [Thymeleaf Module for Java 8 Time API compatibility](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time). Maybe in Spring it is OK.

Comment: When using 'dates' I get error neither bindingresult nor plain target object for bean name '#dates' available as request attribute.  In pom.xml I have a dependency thymeleaf-extras-java8time, but when I use '#temporals' I get the same error, but with a different bean name

Comment: its `#temporals` instead of `#dates` i believe for localdate(time) objects