# th:field syntax inside th:each is incorrect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am using spring boot and thymeleaf combination for my project.

Following is the code snippet for Get controller -

```java
@GetMapping("/split")
public String VerticalSplit(Model model) {
    MessageContent messageContent0 = new MessageContent();
    MessageContent messageContent1 = new MessageContent();
    List<MessageContent> messageContentList = new ArrayList<MessageContent>();
    messageContentList.add(0, messageContent0);
    messageContentList.add(1, messageContent1);
    DisplayMessage displayMessage = new DisplayMessage();
    model.addAttribute("displayList", displayService.getAllDisplays());
    model.addAttribute("groupList", groupService.getAllGroups());
    model.addAttribute("messageContentList", messageContentList);
    model.addAttribute("displayMessage", displayMessage);
    return "combo_vertical_split";
}
```

And respective html code is as follows -

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="col-12"> 
   <label class="form-label"> Name of Message </label> 
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Of Message" required="required" th:value="${displayMessage.name}" /> 
  </div> 
  <hr /> 
  <div th:each="messageContent, iStat : ${messageContentList}"> 
   <h6 align="center" th:text="'Section '+${iStat.count}"></h6> 
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="form-label"> Select the content type </label> 
    <select name="messageContentType" id="messageContent" class="form-control" th:onchange="ShowHideTextMediaDiv();" th:field="${messageContent.type}"> <option class="form-select" th:value="Text">Text</option> <option class="form-select" th:value="Image">Image</option> <option class="form-select" th:value="Video">Video</option> </select> 
    <br /> 
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I am trying to load the page, i am getting error as follows -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'messageContent' available as request attribute
```

The point which I am not getting is that even though I have declared the messageContent in controller, why am i getting the above mentioned error.

I tried multiple syntax of

```
th:field="${messageContent.type}"
```

as follows -

```
th:field="*{messageContent.type}" //its silly as i have not declared the form object but still i tried
th:field="${messageContentList[__${iStat.index}__].type}"
```

and few other combinations as well, but nothing worked and almost everytime i got the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198050/what-causes-java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-ta)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `Neither Bindingnor plain target...` error because you have used the `th:field` in your HTML, but you haven't defined an object from which to bind to it.

You can add your input elements in a `form` element and add a `th:object` attribute bound to your model's `messageContent` object.

You can do something similar to this:

```html
<form th:object="${messageContent}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label"> Select the content type </label>
    <select name="messageContentType" id="messageContent" class="form-control" th:onchange="ShowHideTextMediaDiv();" th:field="*{type}">
      <option class="form-select" th:value="Text">Text</option>
      <option class="form-select" th:value="Image">Image</option>
    </select>
    <br />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but here I have two objects getting populated one is display message and other is message content. so as per my knowledge I cant add single object at form level, because of which I am doing it at field level. please let me know in case I am missing something.